# How to keep background from swiping to right (using jQuery mmenu)

Tags: jquery, css, background, mmenu

I'm building a new website and I want to use jQuery.mmenu on mobile phones. So far so good, except for my background. Just as everything on the page, it slides to the right when I open the jQuery.mmenu, but it kind of keeps a layer and creates another one which slides to the right.

I just want my background stuck, without a slide whatsoever. Can anybody help me and does anybody have a tip for where I need to start looking? I have no idea.

Please see these to understand what I mean:
[Unopened menu (like it should be)](http://s3.postimg.org/d158ohiib/unopened.jpg) and 
[Opened (not okay)](http://s27.postimg.org/okzamcqlf/opened.jpg)

```
*{margin:0;padding:0}
body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/background.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed; 
    background-position: top center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666
}
```

Thanks in advance, I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed it myself. In case somebody has the same problem, look for this piece of code in jquery.mmenu.all.css and remove it:

```
html.mm-background .mm-page { background: inherit; }
```